# how to memset a unicode string in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-string

I have a unicode string f. I want to memset it to 0. print f should display null (\0)

I am using ctypes.memset to achieve this -

```
>     >>> f
>     u'abc'
>     >>> print ("%s" % type(f))
>     <type 'unicode'>
>     >>> import ctypes
>     **>>> ctypes.memset(id(f)+50,0,6)**
>     **4363962530
>     >>> f
>     u'abc'
>     >>> print f
>     abc**
```

Why did the memory location not get memset in case of unicode string?
It works perfectly for an str object.

Thanks for help.

Comment: A `PyUnicode_Object` doesn't have the same internal format as a `PyString_Object`, so there's no reason to expect that the same offset will find the buffer for both.

Comment: Also, this should go without saying, but… this is a really bad idea for any purpose but exploring the implementation of CPython. The interpreter expects strings to be immutable, and all kinds of things can break if you violate that.

Comment: @abarnert, I need to clear a unicode string from the memory from a security perspective. I checked the offset in my system is 50. >>> sys.getsizeof(u'')
50

Comment: Where did you get the idea that that meant the offset to the buffer is 50?

Comment: I read it somewhere and also the offset for a string type is 37 in my system which is what sys.getsizeof('') shows -> >>> sys.getsizeof('')
37. May be I am wrong about the unicode then? Is there a way to clear the memory location containing the unicode string?

Comment: No, the offset for a string type is 36, not 37. (And that's only valid on 64-bit Python—and only on most, not all, 64-bit platforms). And that's not some magic rule you can just apply to any type; it's something you have to figure out by looking at how the C struct is defined and understanding the C layout rules for your platform.

Comment: I've written an answer that explains how to do this—but really, really, really don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

First, this is almost certainly a very bad idea. Python expects strings to be immutable. There's a reason that even the C API won't let you change their contents after they're flagged ready. If you're just doing this to play around with the interpreter's implementation, that can be fun and instructive, but if you're doing it for any real-life purpose, you're probably doing something wrong.

In particular, if you're doing it for "security", what you almost certainly really want to do is to not create a `unicode` in the first place, but instead create, say, a `bytearray` with the UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoding of your string, which can be zeroed out in a way that's safe, portable, and a lot easier.

---

Anyway, there's no reason to expect that two completely different types should store their buffers at the same offset.

---

In CPython 2.x, a `str` is a [`PyStringObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/stringobject.h#L35):

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    long ob_shash;
    int ob_sstate;
    char ob_sval[1];
} PyStringObject;
```

That `ob_sval` is the buffer; the offset should be 36 on 64-bit builds and (I think) 24 on 32-bit builds.

In a comment, you say:

> I read it somewhere and also the offset for a string type is 37 in my system which is what sys.getsizeof('') shows -> >>> sys.getsizeof('') 37

The offset for a string buffer is actually 36, not 37. And the fact that it's even that close is just a coincidence of the way `str` is implemented. (Hopefully you can understand why by looking at the `struct` definition—if not, you *definitely* shouldn't be writing code like this.) There's no reason to expect the same trick to work for some other type without looking at its implementation.

---

A `unicode` is a [`PyUnicodeObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/unicodeobject.h#L415):

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    Py_ssize_t length;          /* Length of raw Unicode data in buffer */
    Py_UNICODE *str;            /* Raw Unicode buffer */
    long hash;                  /* Hash value; -1 if not set */
    PyObject *defenc;           /* (Default) Encoded version as Python
                                   string, or NULL; this is used for
                                   implementing the buffer protocol */
} PyUnicodeObject;
```

Its buffer is not even inside the object itself; that `str` member is a pointer to the buffer (which is not guaranteed to be right after the struct). Its offset should be 24 on 64-bit builds, and (I think) 20 on 32-bit builds. So, to do the equivalent, you'd need to read the pointer there, then follow it to find the location to memset.

If you're using a narrow-Unicode build, it should look like this:

```
>>> ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint16 * len(g)).from_address(id(g)+24).contents[:]
[97, 98, 99]
```

That's the ctypes translation of finding `(uint16_t *)(((char *)g)+24)` and reading the array that starts at `*that` and ends at `*(that+len(g))`, which is what you'd have to do if you were writing C code and didn't have access to the `unicodeobject.h` header.

(In the the test I just quoted, `g` is at 0x10a598090, while its `src` points to `0x10a3b09e0`, so the buffer is not immediately after the struct, or anywhere near it; it's about 2MB before it.)

For a wide-Unicode build, the same thing with `c_uint32`.

So, that should show you what you want to `memset`.

And you should also see a serious implication for your attempt at "security" here. (If I have to point it out, that's yet another indication that you should not be writing this code.)

Comment: @DS' Print out the value in the pointer `ctypes.c_char_p.from_addrss(id(g)+24)`. (That's obviously not the correct pointer type, but since we're not going to deref it or pointer-arithmetic it, just read the address it points to, I used the easiest on to type.)

Comment: @DS' Although really, I'd create a `ctypes.Structure` to represent the `PyUnicodeObject` and then just look at `PyUnicodeObject.from_address(id(g)).str`, which would already be a `POINTER(c_uint16)`. [I did the equivalent](https://github.com/abarnert/superhackyinternals) for Python 3.4' to convince myself I understood how the new, much more complicated internal string representation worked.